# SQL Report Builder 2014 ignores Arial Font and Report uses Helvetica instead

Tags: fonts, rdl, navision, ssrs-2014, dynamics-nav-2016

When Font is set to Arial inside the SQL Report Builder 2014 Report for Navision 2016, the generated PDF file doesn't use Arial but Helvetica instead. When looking at the .rdl file, the  tag is missing at every Filed that is using Arial or in other words the Arial font is not in the xml of the .rdl file.
[XML with Arial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARTW8.png)
When using a different font eg. Segoe UI the font is part of the XML and also correctly generated in the PDF file.
[XML with Segoe UI font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnTtW.png)
The main issue is that we want to have all fonts embedded inside the pdf, but couldn't do it for the reports that are created with Arial.
[Font Helvetica and not embedded in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNN3m.png)
[Font Segoe UI and embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BtIj.png)

The obvious workaround would be to change the font in every filed an report, but that is a lot of work and doesn't solve the issue itself of Arial not being used and Helvetica being used instead (even though Helvetica is not installed on the windows server and also not displayed in the options). We tried to reinstall the Arial font but it didn't help. I also tried to manually change the XML File FontFamily back to Arial and upload it but after compiling and reopening the Layout the XML FontFamily field is gone.